# How to specify a character range on Google Sheets conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to color cells that do not start with a letter; but I'm not sure how to specify a character range in this format.

Cells contents such as:

```
!this one    <--- formatted
this is fine
@email.com   <--- formatted
 leading space   <--- formatted
```

Ideally, it would color the cell for any non-letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Formula

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,"^[^a-zA-Z]")
```

## Explanation

Set conditional formatting to use a custom formula.
Apply the above formula.

- The first ^ means start of the string
- Note that the second ^ is inside of [], this means a logical NOT.
- The a-zA-Z are a two character ranges, lowercase letters and uppercase  letters.

[image]

## References

- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) (Google Docs editors Help)
- [Getting started with Regular Expressions](http://Getting%20started%20with%20Regular%20Expressions) (Documentation - Stack Overflow )

Comment: I didn't realize there was a Regex function; great, I'll look into that more. Thanks again.